# Running ANOVA with Chisq in R and not getting a p-value?

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, anova

I'm running an ANOVA with a chi square test in R to test for individual significance on the response variable and interactions between explanatory variables. For some reason, when I test the relationship between time (explanatory) and a variable called casualty code (explanatory), I'm not getting a p-value in my output.
I'm doing my dissertation on the factors that affect the survival of wildlife during the rehabilitation process. Many of my factors are categorical, however time spent in center is continuous. I've run a GLM fit with a logit function for the response variable "result" (binomial, lived or died), as a factor of time, age (categorical), species type (categorical), and casualty code (injury type, categorical).

```
analysis.time<-glm(Result~Time + Species.Typefac + Codefac + Agefac, family = binomial, data = GBH_Data)
```

I then remove time to test for significance with ANOVA:

```
acst.sigtime<-update(analysis.time,~.-Time)
anova(analysis.time, acst.sigtime, test = "Chisq")
```

Which works just fine. I did the same for interactions between time and age and time and species type and got a normal output. However, when I try and and run the same test for time and casualty code I'm not getting a p-value. This is the code:

```
time.interactions.code<-acs.interactions.weight<-glm(Result~Time + Agefac + Codefac + Species.Typefac + Time:Codefac, family = binomial, data = GBH_Data)
time.code.anova<-update(time.interactions.code,~.-Time:Codefac)
anova(time.code.anova, time.interactions.code, test = "Chisq")
```

And this is the output:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: Result ~ Time + Agefac + Codefac + Species.Typefac
Model 2: Result ~ Time + Agefac + Codefac + Species.Typefac + Time:Codefac
  
Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
  
29561         25297                           
29554         25472        7         -174.6
```

For time:age and time:species type I'm using the exact same code, and I'm getting p-values. Casualty code has 8 categories, while age has 3 and species type has 4. I've double-checked my data and don't have any NAs/blanks. For context, my overall dataset is very large (over 28,000 individual casualties). What could be the reason I'm not getting a p-value here? Answers in lay terms are greatly appreciated, I don't have a lot of experience with statistics so I'm thankful for any simplification of concepts/elaboration of terms.

Comment: In comparism to other test statistics you are getting as result, is -174.6 rather large? Maybe this test statistic is large, thus the p-value very small (~0} and for some reason (bug) not element of the output. I am not really convinced by this explanation, tbh.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.